# How do I divide the columns of a matrix by the sum of its elements?

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks, matrix

I am trying to create a transition matrix for a network.  In order to do this, I need to sum down the column (the out degree), and then divide the column by the out degree in order to normalize it.

I am able to sum down the column.  What I am unable to figure out how to do efficiently and easily is to divide the column by the sum.

```
L = {{0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, 
     {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, 
     {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, 
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, 
     {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, 
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}};
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you need to do this with all columns, then:

```
Transpose[#/Total[#] & /@ Transpose[L]]
```

Comment: Where can I learn how to write these one liners that are so powerful?  I never seem to fully understand the notation.

Comment: @user2200667 there is a tutorial collection [**Core Language**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/CoreLanguageOverview.html) - I'd start there. But also you can start by looking up in documentation symbols like `/@` `&`  `#` `//` etc.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `Normalize` with its second argument for this purpose:

```
(mat = Normalize[#, Total] & /@ Transpose@L // Transpose) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Instead, if you were normalizing the rows by the sum of their elements, you could simply leave out the transposes and do

```
mat = Normalize[#, Total] & /@ L
```

or even

```
mat = #/Tr@#& /@ L
```

---

For your specific problem (transition matrix), you can use the new Markov process related functions in version 9 to get the transition matrix:

```
With[{m = DiscreteMarkovProcess[, L]},
   mat = MarkovProcessProperties[m, "TransitionMatrix"]
] // MatrixForm
```

Answer (score 4):

Why transpose when you don't have to?

```
#/Total[L] & /@ L
```

(Just resurrecting this for a bit of "code golf.")

Comment: The answer to my silly rhetorical question is: because it is faster. My "shorter" code results in longer computational time. The solution using `Transpose` will divide each row (which was, originally, a column) by a single value, List / Real. My answer divides each row by the list of column totals, List / List. At any large scale, this adds up to cost way more than 2x `Transpose`. There's a long comment for a short answer.