# Create a random array totaling a given value with given numbers

Tags: matrix, random, list-manipulation

I have to create a random 16x16 array filled so that the sum of the entire flattened array is 500 (e.g. the sum I'd need for the array `{{0,0,1,0},{1,2,1,2},{0,0,0,0},{3,0,1,0}}` is 11).

I'd like also to use only integer numbers in range form 0 to 5.

Comment: by "sum among every cell" do you mean the sum of every column, row, or both?

Comment: probably related: [22288](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22288/5478)

Comment: @Artes brings up a point I hadn't considered.  Aside from the ambiguity mentioned above, do you want the array filled with real numbers or integers?

Comment: Edit: I meant the total sum of the array (e.g. in `{{0,0,1,0},{1,2,1,2},{0,1,3,0},{0,0,0,0}}` the sum I'd need is 11). Sorry if I couldn't explain properly.

Comment: @RiccardoCazzin It sounds like you want `# (35000/Total[#, 2]) & @ RandomReal[{0, 1}, {16, 16}]`

Comment: 16x16x5 = 1280. How do you expect to get 35000??

Comment: Touché, @george2079, touché. I messed up two different situations: (128*128, 35000) and (16*16, 500).
I made too many mistakes: I don't know whether I should "shamequit"

Comment: This had four close votes on it for "unclear what you are asking."  Rather than let it be closed that way I marked it as a duplicate as I think that is probably more useful to all involved.  Of course if anyone disagrees feel free to voice your opinion!

Comment: The restriction to a small range of allowable values makes this a significantly different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help in the comments (thank you, guys: you are awesome), I achieved what I needed. Just as simple as it looks like:

```
Partition[
 RandomSample[
  RandomChoice[
   IntegerPartitions[
    500, {256}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    ]
   ]
  ], 16]
```

Thank you again!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Table[35000 Normalize[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 16], Total], {16}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I give a version of every cell (**4*4**) is $1$

```
l := RandomReal[1, {4, 4}] // #/Total[#, 2] &
ArrayFlatten[{{l, l}, {l, l}}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]